# How can I group applications in one launcher icon?

Tags: 14.04, launcher, icons, context-menu

Is it possible to create a kind of folder in the launcher that if your mouse is on top of it a menu will appear so I can bundle my programs in groups.

For example, I want to group my creative programs (gimp, stopmotion, scribus) in one icon on the launcher.

Same with my office programs, I want one icon on the launcher and when I move my mouse over it there will display a menu to show the office programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

##Part 1: How to create a New Launcher Item

1. Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Run `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/myApps.desktop`
3. Copy and paste following:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ReplaceWithApplicationName
Comment=
Exec=/path/to/application
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

4. Modify the `Name` (the name of your application), `Exec` (the path to the application), and `Icon` parameters as needed. Save your changes with `File->Save` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.
5. Run `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/myApps.desktop` in Terminal.
6. Run `xdg-open ~/.local/share/applications/` in Terminal; and drag and drop your new launcher Icon onto the launcher.

[image: The newly created launcher icon]

##Part 2 Option A: How to modify right-click menu of a shortcut icon

Ubuntu Tweak is your friend (If you prefer GUI).

1. [Download and Install Ubuntu Tweak](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/) or run the following:

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
   ```
2. Once installed, open Ubuntu Tweak and navigate to *Admins* tab, you’ll see an option called *QuickLists Editor*.

[image: Ubuntu Tweak Admins Tab]

**N.B.** An application needs to be locked in launcher before it can be edited by the *QuickLists Editor*.

3. Add Quick Access Applications in Context Menu of *Launch myApps* icon:

- Select *Launch myApps* in the left
- Click the **+** to add an entry
- Enter the Name (your desired App name) and Command (command that use to start/run your App). In the example screenshot I have added my both browsers. Change the fields as you see fit.
- Click the *Save* button.

[image: Editing an application launcher in the QuickLists editor]

[image: The newly created icon is finished]

##Part 2 (Option B): How to add a menu via text entry

Open the `myApps.desktop` file from part 1, then copy and paste following content for each menu.

```bsh
[Desktop Action Action#]
Name=Name of Applications
Exec=/path/to/application
```

And don't forget to adding number of Actions. for example `Actions=Action1;Action0` in my own icon.

For reference, my launcher icon content is as following:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Launch myApps
Comment=Access to my Applications
Exec=nautilus %U
Icon=/home/username/image.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true

Actions=Action1;Action0

[Desktop Action Action0]
Name=My Chromium
Exec=chromium-browser %U

[Desktop Action Action1]
Name=My Firefox
Exec=firefox %U
```

Sources:
[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/edit-right-click-menu-icons-ubuntu1404/